# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

My spring application compiles successfully but on attempting to load a page I get the below error. Pretty sure it's something related to a dependency in the pom.xml file but I can't really figure out what. Anyone experienced a similar problem before?

```
SEVERE: Error compiling file: /Users/xxx/Documents/scripts/xxx/target/tmp/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/pages/error500_jsp.java
[WARNING] EXCEPTION 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing my pom.xml file from:

```
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jetty.version}</version>
```

to:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
```

It seems to be a jetty version jasper reports compatibility issue. Ideally this fix should work as per this [github issue reply](https://github.com/wakaleo/game-of-life/issues/53#issuecomment-232534399)